# 5 digit number game algorithm

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Hi I need an algorithm for solving this problem.Host thinks of a number 98321 and Guess is 12345. Host would respond with 
ABBCC. 'A' is for 3(correct and middle),'BB' is for 12 correct(but in wrong position) and the CC is for 45(incorrect digits).

Comment: "I need an algorithm for solving this problem". As this is a site for developers, the correct approach is to go ahead and come up with an algorithm and then write the code for it.

Comment: **homework** question. Come up with an idea (and implemention) and discuss this here. No one will write your code for you.

Comment: We will not do your homework for you. Try something yourself first and come here to ask about specific problems.

Comment: you can try simple brute force, with some variant for choosing numbers form valid list by A B and C

Comment: This looks like the "mastermind" game I've programmed over 20 years ago :-) There should be plenty of information on that on the internet nowadays :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly homework, and I won't give you the plain solution for it. However, this exercise game is popular enough for you to find the solution by googling enough.

Anyway, here is some pseudo-code that can help you:

```
guess_game(s1, s2):
    toret = ""

    for i <- 0 to lengthOf( s1 ) - 1:
        is s1[i] == s2[ i ] ?:
            yes: toret += "A"
            no: is s2[ i ] in s1 ?:
                yes: toret += "B"
                no: toret += "C"

    return toret
```

Hope this inspires you enough to take the challenge and get into programming.